# Mouse Down event not being called on the second click

Tags: vb6, mouseevent, picturebox

I have an application in which i'm drawing a line/square on a picturebox. I also need the user to click on a particular point on the picturebox(after drawing the square/line) so as to get the location of the second point. But the mouse down event does not work for the second click. My code is as shown:

```
Dim m_Drawing As Boolean
'm_Drawing = False
Dim m_Startx As Single
Dim m_Starty As Single
Dim m_endx As Single
Dim m_endy As Single
Dim square_click As Boolean
'square_click = False
Dim line_click As Boolean
'line_click = False
Dim bclick As Boolean
'blick = True
Dim startx As Single
Dim starty As Single
Dim endx As Single
Dim endy As Single
Dim laserx_mm As Single
Dim lasery_mm As Single
Dim rectx_mm As Single
Dim recty_mm As Single
Dim xpos As Single
Dim ypos As Single
Dim uxpos As Single
Dim uypos As Single
Dim dist As Single
Dim dist1 As Single

Private Sub Command1_Click()
square_click = True
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
line_click = True
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Dim diffx As Single
Dim diffy As Single

Picture1.Cls
If m_Startx = 0 And m_Starty = 0 Then
m_Startx = X
m_Starty = Y
'End If
startx = X
starty = Y
rectx_mm = X
recty_mm = Y
'move to start position
ElseIf m_Startx <> 0 And m_Starty <> 0 Then
laserx_mm = X
lasery_mm = Y

diffx = rectx_mm - laserx_mm
diffy = recty_mm - lasery_mm

dist = xpos + (diffx / 4.74 / 1000)
dist1 = ypos - (diffy / 4.68 / 1000)

End If
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
endx = X
endy = Y
m_endx = X
m_endy = Y
If square_click = True Then
Picture1.Line (m_Startx, m_Starty)-(endx, endy), vbWhite, B
ElseIf line_click = True Then
Picture1.Line (m_Startx, m_Starty)-(endx, endy), vbWhite
End If
End Sub
```

The Code: `ElseIf m_Startx <> 0 And m_Starty <> 0`

does not get executed unless and until i put a breakpoint there. I'm not sure why this is happening. Please help me out! Hope i was clear enough! Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's not getting executed without the breakpoint? Put in a debug.print to make sure.

Comment: I suggest decorating your code with Debug.Print statements to watch the flow and dump key variables.  Also (seperate from your problem), you have variables endx & m_endx and endy & m_endy that seem to duplicate each other.  Seems like from thins code you should get rid of endx and endy.

Comment: Hi, i just did and yes ure right, it does work. But yeah as i said in my comment to C-Pound Guru, the square is redrawn to the second mouse down point. So i'm not sure what's wrong. thanks!

Comment: okay all u did was changed this:                                  Private Sub Picture1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
If m_endx = 0 And m_endy = 0 Then
m_endx = X
m_endy = Y
If square_click = True Then
Picture1.Line (m_Startx, m_Starty)-(m_endx, m_endy), vbBlack, B
ElseIf line_click = True Then
Picture1.Line (m_Startx, m_Starty)-(m_endx, m_endy), vbBlack
End If
End If
End Sub                                                               But now, the square is erased on the second click. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I threw a `Debug.Print "Here I am"` call inside your `ElseIf m_Startx <> 0 And m_Starty <> 0`...Works like a charm on the 2nd click.  Perhaps you may want to go with a darker color or a thicker line?  The white line is fairly hard to see.

Comment: hi @C-Pound Guru, your right, it does work. But the only issue i have is my square gets extended to that point. Which i don't want. I want to only get the location of the second mouse down point. Not sure if i'm on the right track.. thanks for the help!